# Collatz Conjecture: Unclear on the last argument for Lemma 8 in the paper by Simon & Weger 2005

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, collatz-conjecture

I am reading through the 2005 [paper](https://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35%5DSidW-3n+1-ActaArith%5B2005%5D.pdf) by Simons and Weger on the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Lemma 8 has the following conclusion:

$$\delta K < K +L < 1.000001\delta K$$

I am clear on most of the argument.  I am clear on this point:

$$0 < K+L - \delta K < \frac{m}{X_0\log 2} \le \frac{K}{X_0\log 2} < 10^{-17}K$$

I can see how "the inequalities readily follow" but when I do my calculations, I am reaching a conclusion significantly better.  I am wondering if I am making a mistake since it is not clear to me why the author would be reporting a weaker result.

When I add $\delta K$ to both sides, I get this:

$$\delta K < K + L < 10^{-17}K + \delta K = (10^{-17} + \delta)K < (6.31 \times 10^{-18} + 1)\delta K$$ which appears to be a better result than the conclusion.

Is my reasoning correct and the conclusion is provided to greatly simplify the result?  Did I make a mistake in my reasoning?

If my reasoning is correct, can this result then be restated for example as:

$$\delta K < K + L < 1.0000000001\delta K$$

Comment: Hmm, I cannot well follow the paper, but about your third equation: what do you mean by adding a constant to an inequality and factoring out another one and then add a new $\lt$ clause and then concluding that this can give a better upper(?)/lower(?) bound? Don't misunderstand me: I like to see any improvement especially drawn out of that paper! Unfortunately I don't see either the derivation towards your last inequality.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I am trying to reproduce the conclusion of the lemma.  That might be my mistake.  I am using $\frac{10^{-17} }{\delta}= 6.31 \times 10^{-18}$ to get to $10^{-17} + \delta = (6.31 \times 10^{-18} + 1)\delta$  Did I make a mistake?

Comment: LarryFreeman - maybe I'm on the wrong track (it's perhaps too early morning): what I see is that on the rhs you add by the $\lt$-clause one more expression, but which seems trivial/arbitrary to me and I cannot see how this ***relaxed upper bound*** could add some more precision to the original statement of the lemma? I'm just noticing the answer of John Omielan, perhaps he makes it clearer for me...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms The upper bound of $1 + 6.31 \times 10^{-18}$ is not *relaxed* compared to the paper authors' upper bound of $1.000001$, but is actually considerably more constrained.

Comment: LarryFreeman - ah, I think I'm getting it (authors give too few zeros befor the next significant $1$). Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @LarryFreeman In calculus especially, $\delta$ often refers to a very small quantity (e.g., in $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs for limits). I was expecting this here and was surprised when I solved your question to get a value of $\delta$ that seemed quite "large". Thus, I checked the linked paper to see it's a fixed value that meets your conditions. I suggest that, especially where it's quite important and relatively easy to include, you give the definitions of any important values or expressions, including where they come from (e.g., page #, and even section of the page), like I did in my answer.

Comment: @johnomielan Great point.  An easy step that will make my questions clearer and provide better context for my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your extra inequality of

$$(10^{-17} + \delta)K \lt (6.31 \times 10^{-18} + 1)\delta K \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

is, after dividing by $K$ and then subtracting $\delta$ from both sides, equivalent to

$$10^{-17} \lt 6.31 \times 10^{-18}\delta \iff \frac{10}{6.31} = 1.5847\ldots \lt \delta \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since the paper gives, near the top of page $53$ before its Lemma $1$, that

$$\delta = \frac{\log 3}{\log 2} = 1.5849\ldots \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

and assuming this definition is not changed anywhere later, which a scan of the paper seems to indicate this being the case, this means \eqref{eq2A} is true.

I don't know why the authors didn't use more decimal digits (e.g., up to $16$ zeroes before a $1$ instead of using just $5$ zeroes) to state a tighter upper bound, but possibly they felt there wasn't any need for the extra accuracy for their purposes.